# Subtitle Edit won't let me choose a video engine

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, subtitles

I'm using Subtitle Edit to make subtitles for a video, it is supposed to let the user choose between several video engines, one of them is VLC. I can only choose DirectShow since the other options are [disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2Lz0.png). I have installed the latest version of both programs and the LAV splitters, nothing seems to be working. I'd appreciate some help.

OS: Win 7 
VLC: 2.2.4
SubEdit:3.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your computer 32-bit or 64-bit? You must install the VLC version equivalent to your computer. If it still doesn't work, reinstall VLC. I had to reinstall VLC 64-bit version twice to make it work.

http://www.nikse.dk/SubtitleEdit/Help#codecs

Comment: Very true ! and the 64bits version of VLC is hidden in the drop down menu of the platform download button http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that you have installed it under `c:\programfiles` or some directory that has read/write issues.

If you `install` Subedit under a "normal" folder, things starts to work as supposed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem and realized that i was using the 32 bit version of subtile edit while I have 64 bit windows, so I just downloaded the 64 bit version and everything works fine now

Answer (score 0):

I could not select Media Classic Player when reinstalled SE because I upgraded to Windows 8.1. I tried many different things but did not work. Finally, I then realized it might because the codecs (K-Lite) were installed in the D drive. I uninstalled and reinstalled them in C and the problem was solved!